# Simple jQuery post question (using Django)

Tags: django, jquery

sing django and jQuery

I am trying to implement a button that, using the post method, would send an id of a field to be deleted from the db.

**feed_list.html**

```
<form id="get_feed_frm">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for news in new_feed %}
<ul class = {{news.pk}}>

    <button id = {{news.pk}}>  Remove</button>
     <script>
        $("#{{news.pk}}").click(function () { 
                $('ul').remove('.{{news.pk}}');
                $.post('/?ajax', { csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), id: '{{news.pk}}'});
                }) </script>
    {{ news.question }}
    <hr />
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

I can achieve the desired result with this code. However, when I remove the

```
$('ul').remove('.{{news.pk}}');
```

line from my script, the function doesn't work, and i cannot explain why it's the case. I would really appreciate your input on this.

-r

**EDIT:**

Thx Yuji I learned a couple of tricks that will help me better write my code. However I still have the same problem.

I posted below my view code as I must be doing something fundamentally wrong with my view or the way I send the post method

```
def recent_feed_view(request):

print "Entering View"
new_feed = []
if 'id' in request.POST:
    delete_id = request.POST['id'].strip()
    print "____id____" #just for debugging purpuse
    print delete_id
    n = news.objects.get(pk=delete_id)
    n.discarded = True
    n.save()

new_feed = news.objects.filter(discarded = False)

variables = RequestContext(request, {'new_feed': new_feed})

if 'ajax' in request.POST:
    print "______AJAX_______"

return render_to_response('feed_list.html', variables)
```

EVerytime I run the site, The URL correctly links the execution to the correct view, and I get the following message in the command prompt:

```
[06/Mar/2011 16:59:38] "GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken=e724dfb883965aaa0edfb6ef521a885c HTTP/1.1" 200 1017
```

**EDIT**

Yuji, (thx for introducing me to Chrom dev tool! I am still a newbie and learning a lot thanks to you!)

I followed your advice 
2 things happened for me here:

running this code in the Chrome dev tool:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/?ajax',
                data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                id:44
                    }
                });
```

the dev server received a post: The correct entry was discarded from my code, and i had to manually refresh the page to see the changes made

```
Entering View
____id____
44
[06/Mar/2011 18:20:27] "POST /?ajax HTTP/1.1" 200 1203
```

Incorporating the above script in my site I would receive:

```
Entering View
 ____id____
45
[06/Mar/2011 18:29:18] "POST /?ajax HTTP/1.1" 200 968
Entering View
[06/Mar/2011 18:29:18] "GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken=e724dfb883965aaa0edfb6ef521a885c HTTP/1.1" 200 968
```

For some reason I am getting a POST and a GET; I used this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".remove-button").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/?ajax',
                data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                id:$(this).attr('id')
                    }
                });
        })
    })
       </script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I still find it supremely odd that it works if you remove the previous line. Also, now I see the dev server thinks its a GET request, but I can't reproduce that problem even if I `$.post("/?get-params", {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't see why removing that line would prevent the `$.post` line from happening, I'm going to start suggesting [fixing some syntax problems](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) that the browser may be having trouble parsing.

You need quotes around the values you're putting in for class name and button id.

Those lines were causing trouble for my syntax highlighter, so who knows...

```
<ul class = "{{news.pk}}">
    <button id = "{{news.pk}}">  Remove</button>
```

---

Also this part is just a suggestion, but instead of embedding a `<script>` per row, you should do something like adding a class to each button so that you only have to define your jquery action once.

Consider this: `<button id = "{{news.pk}}" class="remove-button">  Remove</button>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".remove-button").click(function() {
            $.post('/?ajax', { 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                id: $(this).attr('id')
                });
        })
    })
</script>
```

---

The dev server is thinking it's a GET request -- can you try manually using the `$.ajax` function? I wonder if a previous version of jQuery got confused with you passing in get params to your POST?

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/?ajax',
  data: {
       csrfmiddlewaretoken: $(...),
       id: ...
  }
});
```

PS: This is a place where google chrome dev tools or firebug come in really handy, you can just type away raw jquery commands :)

Comment: Thx for the insights on how to fix the syntax problem and better write the code. I have added my Django view in an EDIT in my question, I'd really appreciate if you could lend me a hand here :)

Comment: I updated some info in the second edit of my question; I think this will help: the first time that I run the $.ajax({ type: 'POST'... code (by pressin the button and not from the dev tool), I receive a POST then a GET request. The site URL in the browser then changes to: http://localhost:8000/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=... ;

Comment: I haven't completely solved it: first it is not a problem with jquery as I am able to request a post from the Dev tool. The Get I was receiving was because I had my buttons inside a form '<form id="get_feed_frm">' ; for some reason firefox and Chrom (but not IE) was requesting a get with the same data as the one in the post. I replace the form with a div class. Right now I only get one post, with the correct parameters appended to it.

Comment: I also put my the csrf token inside a div class '<div id="csrf_token">{% csrf_token %}</div>' I am not sure how this contributed to the solution. The only reason I said I have not completely solved it is because I still cannot explain why the post method was being ignored,

Comment: and Yuji, I cannot begin to say how much I appreciate your help throughout this thread, and your follow up on the issue! It would have probably taken me twice as long if not for your tips on using the dev tool, the html syntax error, and the alternative way to write the the post in ajax.

Comment: Awesome! No problem Rami, I think it's pretty great that you dug into it / came back to share the story :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jQuery to retrive the token from cookies set by Django and set the correct header to use in every jQuery.ajax and jQuery.post.

```
(function($){
    if(!$) {
        return;
    }

    var match = document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=(\w+)/);
    var token = match ? match[1] : '';

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': token }
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```